# How To Solve This Complicated Coding Interview Problem?

Tags: python, mysql, algorithm

I recently had a coding interview which I failed to pass.

however, after the coding interview I'm still trying to fix their problem I have fixed the first problem but I don't know if I did it the right way or not, and the rest of them I can't solve them.

if you please review my first question answer and if you give me a solution to the rest of the question and explain that would be awesome :)

**Here is Coding Problem.**

```
# A healthcare tech company has a number of activity records for each Health # Advocate (each "HA"). Each activity record is represented by a list of # 3-element tuples as follows:

activity = [
    (1, '@login', None),
    (5, '@startVideo', 'Bob'),
    (20, '@startVideo', 'Thomas'),
    (66, '@stopVideo', 'Thomas'),
    (70, '@startVideo', 'Lily'),
    (75, '@stopVideo', 'Bob'),
    (78, '@stopVideo', 'Lily'),
    (100, '@logout', None),
    (150, '@login', None),
    (160, '@startVideo', 'Thomas'),
    (205, '@stopVideo', 'Thomas'),
    (210, '@logout', None)
]

# For each tuple, the first element is timestamp, the second is an action (e.g., # '@login', '@startVideo', '@stopVideo', '@logout'), and the last element is # the client. In detail, for example, (1, '@login', None) means this HA logged # in to our system at time 1, (100, '@logout', None) means this HA logged out of # our system at time 100, (5, '@startVideo', 'Bob') means that this HA started # a video stream with the client Bob at time 5, and (75, '@stopVideo', 'Bob') # means that this HA ended the video stream with Bob at time 75.

# Although each HA is free to video stream with zero, one, or two clients at any # moment in time, the company encourages HAs to simultaneously video stream # with two clients as much as possible. Note that every HA can stream with a # maximum of two clients at any moment.

# So, your challenge is to calculate both (A) the duration of this example HA's # logged in time, e.g. the sum of all periods between '@login' and '@logout', and # (B) the duration of this example HA's time spent simultaneously streaming video # with two clients.

# For the above example, the correct result for (A) is 159 (1 to 100, 150 to 210)
# and the correct result for (B) is 51 (20 to 66, 70 to 75).

# Note that the activity list is sorted by timestamp, and you can assume all test data # are valid. Please be sure that your solution code outputs BOTH (A) and (B).

# YOUR SOLUTION PYTHON CODE HERE

def find_login_and_logout_time(activity):

    num = None
    values = []

    for x in activity:

        if "login" in x[1]:
            num = x[0]
        elif "logout" in x[1]:
            values.append(x[0] - num)

    return sum(values)


time = find_login_and_logout_time(activity)
print(time)




######################## MYSQL #########################

# The healthcare tech company has a MySQL table, named `chats`, recording all # messages between Health Advocates ("HAs") and clients.

# The schema of table `chats` is as follows:

# create table chats (id int auto_increment primary key, ha varchar(10), client varchar(10), message varchar(255), timestamp bigint);

# The data of table `chats` is below

# insert into chats values (1, 'Lily', 'Adam', '@startVideo', 1563733280), (2, 'Ava', 'Bob', '@startVideo', 1563733283), (3, 'Susan', 'Ruth', '@startVideo', 1563733290), (4, 'Lily', 'Adam', 'Good to see you again!', 1563733292), (5, 'Lily', 'Adam', 'Sure, I can do that for you.', 1563733310), (6, 'Lily', 'Adam', 'All set! No worries at all.', 1563733330), (7, 'Lily', 'Adam', '@stopVideo', 1563733334), (8, 'Ava', 'Bob', 'Yes, that is so funny! haha!', 1563733335), (9, 'Ava', 'Bob', '@stopVideo', 1563733356), (10, 'Susan', 'Bob', '@StartVideo', 1563733357), (11,'Susan', 'Bob', '@stopVideo', 1563733370), (12,'Susan', 'Ruth', 'Hello, Ruth, are you here?', 1563733371), (13,'Susan', 'Ruth', '@stopVideo', 1563733378);

# A message can be either a command (e.g., @startVideo, and @stopVideo) or # a speech phrase sent from the HA to the client. An "interaction" between an # HA and a client is defined as the messages between that HA/client from # '@startVideo' to '@stopVideo' (inclusive).

# For example, using the above values, the interaction between Lily and Adam # is as follows: # (1, 'Lily', 'Adam', '@startVideo', 1563733280), # (4, 'Lily', 'Adam', 'Good to see you again!', 1563733292), # (5, 'Lily', 'Adam', 'Sure, I can do that for you.', 1563733310), # (6, 'Lily', 'Adam', 'All set! No worries at all.', 1563733330), # (7, 'Lily', 'Adam', '@stopVideo', 1563733334)

# And the interaction between Ava and Bob is as follows: # (2, 'Ava', 'Bob', '@startVideo', 1563733283), # (8, 'Ava', 'Bob', 'Yes, that is so funny! haha!', 1563733335), # (9,'Ava', 'Bob', '@stopVideo', 1563733356)

# An interaction between an HA and a client is "significant" if its duration is # at least 30 seconds.

# For each client, please output the timestamp of @stopVideo of the # last significant interaction, ordering by client alphabetically.

# Based the above data, your query should output the following: # client last_significant_interaction # Adam 1563733334 # Bob 1563733356 # Ruth 1563733378

# YOUR SOLUTION MYSQL QUERY HERE
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far for (B)?

Comment: @sabik I'm just thinking of (B) how should I do it I didn't find any solution yet basically nothing.

Comment: If you were working it out by hand, going through the list, how would you do it? What information would you have to keep track of from row to row?

Answer (score 0):

The logic here can be very similar to what you did for the login times, the only difference is that you need to check for *two* simultaneously active videos.
To keep the same structure of your code we may have something like

```
def find_times(activity):
    logtimes = []
    videotimes = []
    currvideos = 0
    for x in activity:
        if "login" in x[1]:
              logstart = x[0]
        elif "logout" in x[1]:
              logtimes.append(x[0] - logstart)
        elif "startVideo" in x[1]:
              currvideos += 1
              if currvideos == 2:
                  videostart = x[0]
        elif "stopVideo" in x[1]:
              currvideos -= 1
              if currvideos == 1:
                  videotimes.append(x[0] - videostart)
    return (sum(logtimes), sum(videotimes))
              
>>> find_times(activity)
(159, 51)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go over the log in a loop, then there is no need to occupy expensive extra memory and executing expensive array doubling (i.e. `.append`). It is enough to keep certain information about the current state of the login system, i.e. it is enough to keep track of the set of variables:

```
time-stamp = activity[i][0] 
action = activity[i][1] 
number of current streams 
total time spent logged in 
total time streaming two clients
```

We do not care about the names of the clients, what matter are simply the order of action. This is due to the nature of the log and the restriction that there can be no more than two simultaneous streams.

So I think the following code takes care of the task:

```py
def login_and_double_streaming_times(activity):
    total_login_time = 0
    total_double_streaming = 0    
    current_streams = 0
    for entry in activity:
        if entry[1] == '@login':
            total_login_time = total_login_time - entry[0] 
        elif entry[1] == '@startVideo': 
            current_streams = current_streams + 1
            if current_streams == 2:
                total_double_streaming = total_double_streaming - entry[0]
        elif entry[1] == '@stopVideo':
            current_streams = current_streams - 1
            if current_streams == 1:
               total_double_streaming = total_double_streaming + entry[0] 
        elif entry[1] == '@logout':
            total_login_time  = total_login_time + entry[0] 
            current_streams = 0
    return  total_login_time, total_double_streaming
```